# MySQL query order the results in GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

I'm coding a forum system and I'm trying to get the last post in a topic. The problem is I'm grouping the results on the topic id and I can't figure out a way to get the last reply to be displayed in the grouped data.

Here is my query so far:

```
   SELECT SQL_CACHE users.user_id, 
          users.username, 
          topics.title, 
          topics.topic_id,
          topics.previews,
          topics.date_added,
          posts.post_id, 
          last.username AS last_username, 
          last.user_id AS last_user_id, 
          MAX( posts.post_id ) AS last_post_id,
          posts.date_added AS last_data
     FROM `topics`
LEFT JOIN `users` ON users.user_id = topics.user_id
LEFT JOIN `posts` ON ( posts.topic_id = topics.topic_id )
LEFT JOIN `users` AS last ON ( last.user_id = posts.user_id )
    WHERE fcat_id = '2'
 GROUP BY topics.topic_id
```

Comment: The query doesn't make a lot of sense without knowing the tables

Comment: Are you trying to show the last post for different topics on one page or do you just want to show the last post for a particular topic? Can you please clarify

Comment: He's trying to list the topics and for each topic to display its last reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
SELECT *, `last`.`user_id` AS last_user_id FROM
(
    SELECT users.user_id, 
          users.username, 
          topics.title, 
          topics.topic_id,
          topics.previews,
          topics.date_added,
          posts.post_id, 
          MAX( posts.post_id ) AS last_post_id,
          posts.date_added AS last_data
         FROM `topics`
    LEFT JOIN `users` ON users.user_id = topics.user_id
    LEFT JOIN `posts` ON ( posts.topic_id = topics.topic_id )
        WHERE fcat_id = '2'
     GROUP BY topics.topic_id
 ) AS `tst`
LEFT JOIN `posts` ON ( posts.post_id = tst.last_post_id )
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `last` ON ( `last`.user_id = posts.post_id )
```

Just set your selects properly and maybe alias the posts JOIN which is outside the subquery

Answer (score 1):

You can use both group by and order by. The orderby will apply within each group.

So
     GROUP BY topics.topic_id
     ORDER BY post.timestamp

(I was a bit concerned I had the parameter order wrong, but we're good: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

Answer (score 1):

The way that SQL works is that after your WHERE clause, a temporary result set is created. Then the items from the temporary result set are grouped.

This means you have to make sure that all items from the temporary result set, that are grouped into a single final result, share the same values for the fields you want to have (i.e. they are all the "last reply to be displayed in the grouped data").

Instead of the GROUP BY, I would use a subquery that selects the last replies to be displayed and feed that to a suitable WHERE clause.

Comment: If I use a subquery that means to put the subquery into loop (impractical)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is order your results by date_added and limit your result to 1 so it returns the most recent topic. I hope this points you to the right direction

Comment: I tried to ORDER by post_id or date_added (post), but it order topics by posts, not posts in group by.

Comment: @Karo96: Is there a reason why you are doing a LEFT join twice on the users table?

Comment: ok, i will be delete first left join to users, but query respond same.

Answer (score 0):

```
Take it in two easy steps.


You want to find the most recent post in each category, and
then some info related to the post.

So first get the posts of interest:

    SELECT 
        MAX(topic_id) AS topic_id,
        post_id 
    FROM posts
    WHERE fcat_id = '2'
    GROUP BY topic_id

and then get "stuff" by adding on your joins:


SELECT
    tst.topic_id,
    tst.post_id,
    stuff
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        MAX(topic_id) AS topic_id,
        post_id 
    FROM posts
    WHERE fcat_id = '2'
    GROUP BY topic_id
) AS tst
LEFT JOIN users ...
LEFT JOIN topics ...
```