# Using Case and Group By to get Grouped results in a specific order

Tags: mysql, case, subquery

I have asked a similar question in the past, but didn't quite get what I needed, here's the old question

[How do I get the ID of a rows which have MAX and MIN values in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663744/how-do-i-get-the-id-of-a-rows-which-have-max-and-min-values-in-sql)

What I need to do is get a set of data which has grouped all items with the same `item` field in the database, but ensure that the data set outputs the details relating to a specific item ID, so to order the grouping in a specific fashion. (in my case I need to order by either `totalStock` field, or `price`, if `totalStock` then order `desc` if `price`, order `asc`.

I *think* that this SO question answers my question better, but I don't understand the `Joins` I am afraid

[MySQL query order the results in GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929510/mysql-query-order-the-results-in-group-by)

Here's an example of where I'm at:

```
"SELECT * FROM (select *, count(id) as Variants, sum(totalStock) as sumTotalStock 
FROM `products` WHERE id > 0 AND `display`='1' 
GROUP BY item ORDER BY CASE WHEN totalStock > 0 THEN totalStock ELSE price END DESC) 
AS unknownVar 
ORDER BY sumTotalStock"
```

My lose understanding of SQL is aiming to get an inner set of results from my database grouped by `item` with the grouping ordered by `totalStock` if `totalStock > 0` or by `price` otherwise. This inner result set is then order by `sumTotalStock`.

The important bit is

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN totalStock > 0 THEN totalStock ELSE price END
```

This is giving me two issues.

1) some strange output, missing out some content that should be shown.

2) Also, I need to be able to change the sort order

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN totalStock > 0 *DESC* THEN totalStock ELSE price *ASC* END
```

With the astrix'd `DESC` and `ASC` doesn't work, I seem to have to put `DESC` at the end of the `ORDER BY` statement, but then it's ordering `DESC` in either case, which is wrong.

Given the above two issues, I'm not sure this is actually working at all!

I've spent most of the afternoon and all evening on this now with Google and various SO questions, but I'm afraid I've given up and had to post another!

If anyone could post me some code that would sort this I would be eternally grateful!

I'm using a MySQL database, bother the `totalStock` and `price` columns are numeric in all cases and `item` is a `varChar` field. Once I can get this working with these fields I can extract all else I need, so hopefully, you shouldn't need any more than that to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN totalStock > 0 THEN totalStock ELSE -1 * price END) DESC
```

What you were doing before with ASC/DESC is not allowed (and it really shouldn't be if you think about what you were trying to do). Think of that entire CASE statement as a variable column you can't sort the same column two different ways that just wouldn't make sense

Comment: I see, inverting the price... clever! However, whilst it appears to be working the results I am getting are wrong. Here's my development site: http://dev.hartnollguitars.co.uk/Search.aspx?subcategory=Gibson-Les-Pauls&sort=price%20desc this link does not use the case statement, whereas this: http://dev.hartnollguitars.co.uk/Search.aspx?subcategory=Gibson-Les-Pauls&sort=price%20desc&orderCase=yes does. In both links the WHERE clause is the same, but yet the results are different, I thought it was that anything with no stock, or only one item in the "group" was not showing, but it's not that

Comment: Just to clarify how this works, `totalStock` is indicated on the page returned by Stock Level and also where the output says `X Options` that indicates how many grouped items there are, ie, in real life, the grouped items are options (finishes available) so, some products may only have one option, therefore only one item would be returned in the grouped data, sorting in these cases is kind of irrelevant, but the ommission of some items from the result set seems random!

Comment: Looking again, and nore reading, I dont think this is the way to do it. That inner query is being sorted AFTER grouping I think, so it's no good. I need to sort the groups and the only way I know how to do that is with `GROUP_CONCAT` but then it gets really fiddle with getting multiple column data. I think I'm going to have to work out how `joins` work.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you completely. Both of your links returned the same result for me. Did you sort this out? I can assure you that the differences you may have been seeing were definitely not related to changes in the ORDER BY clause. If you need more assistance with joins or want to rewrite the query somehow, it may be best to post a new question with a sample dataset and clearly describe what you want your results to be and what you've tried. It's hard to give you a clearer answer of what you should be doing without a better description of what your data looks like.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I added a different question and got a response which sorted. Thanks!